Xcode 16 error - Use of undeclared identifier '_CTYPE_A'
I just upgraded to Xcode 16.0 and Sequoia 15.0. I have a large, mostly Objective-C project that's giving me the following error. Does anybody know how I can track down this error? I'd love to create a sample project to reproduce it, but I have no idea which part of my project is taking the compiler down this path. Other projects build fine.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:67:10: note: while building module '\_wchar' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:67:
#include \<\_wchar.h\>
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/\_wchar.h:76:10: note: while building module '\__wctype' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/\_wchar.h:76:
#include \<sys/\_types/\_mbstate_t.h\>
^
\<module-includes\>:1:9: note: in file included from \<module-includes\>:1:
#import "\___wctype.h"
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/\___wctype.h:83:24: error: use of undeclared identifier '\_CTYPE_A'
return (\__istype(\_wc, \_CTYPE_A|\_CTYPE_D));
^

There are 100+ lines of similar errors referencing _CTYPE_A, _CTYPE_C, _CTYPE_D, _CTYPE_G, etc.

I've tested this on another Mac that's still running Sonoma. The project compiles on that computer with Xcode 15.4, but gives the same errors with Xcode 16.
UPDATE: This project is for a macOS application (not sure if that matters).

If it's any comfort, you're not alone: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681946

The same issue can be found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/764530

The issue with me was that my project included openSSL static libs and among the include headers was a file "ctype.h", that has the same name as the one of the files in macOS SDK /usr/include folder.
So, yeah, it has to do with "search and discovery" phase of the compiler.
I packed openSSL as a framework and added it to the project, solved this mix-up.

THANK YOU so much! This was it. My project was configured to use openSSL for receipt validation. I ended up moving to Revenuecat but never removed the dependency.

I solved this problem by following these steps:

Open xcode (your project's ios folder or ios/Runner.xcworkspace)
Select Runner
Tap on Build Settings
Find "Apple clang - Language - Modules" or you can just search "allow"
You will see

Allow non-modular Includes In Framework Modules - NO
Change this to "YES"

Then try to run your app again.

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I also tried cleaning the build folder and deleting the DerivedData prior to rebuilding. Same error.

It didn't work for me too
